# WCF: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed

Tags: wcf, wcf-authentication

I have written a very simple WCF Service that sends and receives messages. I have tested the app through the VS 2008 default web server host and everything works fine. But when I deploy the WCF service to another computer's IIS I receive the following error:

**"The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed."**

How can I set the authentication type to use my custom username and password in config file?
If it is not possible, please tell me how I can set its windows credentials because the 2 computers that I'm using, don't share the same users.

Answer (score 30):

You need to turn off security for the binding.  Otherwise, I believe that, by default, the wsHttpBinding will try to negotiate a Security Context Token (SCT).

So, modify the endpoint definition to point to a binding configuration section.  Here's an example:

```
<endpoint address="" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding" 
          contract="HelloWorldService.IService1"
          bindingConfiguration="TheBindingConfig">
```

And then add something like the following binding configuration right after the `<services>` section in the web.config's `<system.serviceModel>` section.

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TheBindingConfig">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Setting security to "None" is the key.

Hope this helped!

---

The above helped me - but what is not immediately obvious is how to add to the *service* end (its clear once you've done it what's needed, but not until you've done so). The reason its not entirely obvious is because there isn't a bindings section by default whereas there is liable to be one in the client.

So, just to be very clear - at the service end, add the bindings section (as detailed above) and then to the appropriate endpoint add the bindingConfiguration="TheBindingConfig" attribute. Obvious once you've done it once...

Comment: I think it's a bad answer to automiticaly go with turning off security

Answer (score 20):

You don't actually need to turn off security and in some cases you shouldn't. Within a bindingConfiguration, you can specify message level security that does not establish a security context as follows:

```
<security mode="Message">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
        algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
</security>
```

Note the establishSecurityContext attribute. Both the client and service should have a security configuration with establishSecurityContext set to the same value. A value of true also works fine but false is recommended in an environment where the servers are load balanced.

Answer (score 12):

Be sure to set this `bindingConfiguration` (specifying security mode 'none') on **both** client and server or else you will get this message - which is quite a red herring as far as debugging the problem.

> The message could not be processed.
>   This is most likely because the action
>   'http://tempuri.org/IInterfaceName/OperationName'
>   is incorrect or because the message
>   contains an invalid or expired
>   security context token or because
>   there is a mismatch between bindings.
>   The security context token would be
>   invalid if the service aborted the
>   channel due to inactivity. To prevent
>   the service from aborting idle
>   sessions prematurely increase the
>   Receive timeout on the service
>   endpoint's binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in debug mode then set the debug attribute as

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
```

by default it sets as false ..so while you go for debugging it throws that exception .

hope it helps .