# WPF Client - WCF allow cross-domain access - Issue

Tags: wpf, wcf

I am really struggling with this one. I have Google'd this and tried most of the solutions without any success.

Some background information:

I have a WPF application which consumes a WCF service. Everything works fine if the service and the application is on the same domain, but as soon as you move the application to another domain, it stops wokiring and gives the following error:

The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.

I worked through the following article: Making a Service Available Across Domain Boundaries[^], which referred to making use of some XML files, which I did, I have tried placing the XML files (clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml) on the IIS server - this did not make any difference (please note that I did place the files within the root of the web service)?!

I can access the web service (client side), by entering the URL in the browser as well as click on the wsdl link and view the XML, but I cannot get it working from my WPF application!

This is my client side config file content:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IManagmentService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://server.local/ManagementDataProvider/ManagmentService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IManagmentService"
            contract="ManagementService.IManagmentService" name="WSHttpBinding_IManagmentService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Could anyone please provide me with some information of how I can access the web service from my application.

Many thanks in advance!
Kind regards,

Comment: If you´re calling the service via browser, is it prompting you for a username/password? I assume the domain hosting the service and the domain hosting the client don´t have a trust relationship, hence your service cannot authenticate the client.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `clientaccesspolicy.xml` and `crossdomain.xml`?

Comment: And does this work with a plain non-secure binding? One without the Transport and Message security? (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/394829/302677)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the issue was resolved by making use of  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx). The issue had nothing to do with cross-domain access. The  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731299.aspx) needs to be satisfied by the security token, thus accessing the web service from an unknown domain (unknown to the DNS), .

Well, this was what solved my issue?!

Kind regards,