# WCF service is working in VS but not in LinqPad

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, linqpad

I am using a .NET API to connect to [WCF Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf) and it works fine in [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) but not in [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/).

- I am using the same code and referencing the same app.config and DLL files in both Visual Studio and in Linqpad.
- Everything is running on my local computer.
- The api is using [.Net Framework 4.8](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net48), so I am using LinqPad 5
- The service is up and running at http://localhost:2001/GenericService and the endpoint configuration looks ok

What can be the cause of this? wish I had more info to share but don't know where to look. I have tried to debug but found nothing of value more than it produces the error when getting the request

here is the error from LinqPad dump

```
Failed to communicate with *** Services. Failed to communicate with server. The caller was not authenticated by the service. The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
```

[image]

Comment: Does your WCF service use Windows authentication?

Comment: No. I specify username and password which works when in visual studio

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2860485/5519709

Comment: thx, tried everything I think, but still couldn't get it to work. I have moved on, back in VS

Comment: Based on the URL, that's Visma's VBS service, right? We're seeing exactly the same thing on a new Win 2019 server - doesn't work from LINQPad 5 or an IIS application, but it *does* work from a Visual Studio console application, even running outside of VS. No idea why yet - maybe something to do with TLS settings?

Comment: Yes. visma services